# Eager load relationship with parameter in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, eager-loading

In my Laravel app, I want to have a relation conditionally load data from one of two tables, depending on a specified parameter.

I have two pivot tables with identical columns, called `driver_route` and `driver_route_history`. They both relate `driver_id` and `route_id` columns. The only difference is `driver_route_history` has a `date` column which holds an absolute date in time (e.g. 06/08/2022), while `driver_route` has a `weekday` column which refers to the current week.

The records in `driver_route` can be modified by the user. At the end of each week, they are cloned to `driver_route_history`, so that changes from week to week are preserved looking back.

I want to be able to pull data for a single day. If the specified day falls within the current week or references a future date, data should be loaded from `driver_route`. If the date falls prior to the start of the current week, data should be pulled from `driver_route_history`.

I have a function that can do this, when called ordinarily as a function from somewhere within the app:

```
    public function driversOnDay($date)
    {
        $carbon_date = Carbon::parse($date);
        if ($carbon_date->isBefore(Carbon::today()->startOfWeek())) {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Driver::class, 'driver_route_history')->wherePivot('date', $carbon_date);
        } else {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Driver::class, 'driver_route')->wherePivot('weekday', strtolower($carbon_date->shortDayName));
        }
    }
```

I would like to load this relation on every Route record using Laravel's eager loading, like such:

```
Route::with(['driversOnDay' => function($query) { ... });
```

How can I include the `driversOnDay` `date` parameter into this eager load call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, model **Route** is associated with **Driver** model via **many-to-many** relationship and you need to join the relation via `driver_route` pivot table if the `$date` is in current week or in future and via `driver_route_history` pivot table if `$date` is older than start of current week.

One way of doing it would be to have two separate relationships defined on the model and then use a scope:

```php
class Route extends Model
{
    public function driversOnDay()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Driver::class, 'driver_route');
    }


    public function driversOnDayHistory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Driver::class, 'driver_route_history');
    }

    public function scopeWithDrivers($query, $date)
    {
        $carbon_date = Carbon::parse($date);
        return $query
            ->when(
                $carbon_date->isBefore(Carbon::today()->startOfWeek()),
                function($query) use($carbon_date){
                    $query->with([
                        'driversOnDayHistory' => function($query) use($carbon_date){
                            $query->wherePivot('weekday', strtolower($carbon_date->shortDayName));
                        }
                    ]);
                },
                function($query) use($carbon_date){
                    $query->with([
                        'driversOnDay' => function($query) use($carbon_date){
                            $query->wherePivot('date', $carbon_date);
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Then you can use the local scope on **Route** model anywhere

```php
$records = Route::query()->withDrivers($date)->get();
```

So if the date is in past `$records` will have `driversOnDayHistory` eager loaded else it will have `driversOnDay` eager loaded.

###### Update

> Is there a way to rename the attribute, so it has the same name in both cases? Right now, the loaded collections are named differently depending on which relation was loaded.

You can manipulate the resulting collection. Say you always want to have the eager loaded relations available as **driversOnDay**, then you can try

```php
$records = Route::query()
    ->withDrivers($date)
    ->get()
    ->map(function($route) {
        if($route->relationLoaded('driversOnDayHistory')) {
            $drivers = $route->driversOnDayHistory;
            $route->unsetRelation('driversOnDayHistory');
            $route->setRelation('driversOnDay', $drivers);
        }

        return $route;
    });
```

Comment: This does the trick, ty! Is there a way to rename the attribute, so it has the same name in both cases? Right now, the loaded collections are named differently depending on which relation was loaded.

Comment: @julianatkin You can achieve it via mapping over the collection received via **get**. Have updated answer. Please check if that's what you meant.